# Nodemon is not working: nodemon is not loading

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mongoose

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongoURI = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=false";

const connectToMongo = ()=>{
    mongoose.connect(mongoURI, ()=>{
        console.log('database connected');
    })
}

module.exports = connectToMongo;
```

index.js

```
const connectToMongo = require('./db');
const express = require('express');

connectToMongo();

const app = express();
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

i have checked dependencies installed nodemon using npm i -D nodemon
when i typed nodemon .\index.js my live server should run but it is not[[image: you can see the nodemon is not in green color ][1]]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is Powershell does not aware of nodemon.
Currently nodemon is installed in your project directory.

I would suggest you to a script in package.json

```
"scripts": {

   "start-nodemon": "nodemon ./index.js"
}
```

And then run in powershell

```
npm run start-nodemon
```

Comment: Alternatively use `npx` to run locally installed commands with `npx nodemon ./index.js` for example.